# PHPExcel: How to check if cell value is a function

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

like in the title when i read an excel file i want to know if cell contain a value or a function.
Is there a bool return method in PHPExcel like this?

```
$cell->getValue()->isFunction();
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not for the value, that wouldn't be possible because the value of a cell is a PHP scalar datatype, like boolean or string or float, so it can't have methods.

But you can tell if a cell contains a formula by calling the ***cell's*** `isFormula()` method, which returns a boolean true/false

```
$cell->isFormula();
```